# Convergence of $h(f(x))$ and $h(f_n(x))$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $h$ and $f$ be any $\mathbb{R\to R}$ functions.

Now suppose $f_n$ converges to $f$: $\mathrm{lim_{n\to\infty}}f_n=f$

Does it also mean that $h(f_n)$ and $h(f)$ are the same in the limit?

I've been browsing top questions and came across this example: [Is value of $\pi = 4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4)

Even though two curves become indistinguishable in the limit, the difference of their lengths is considerably different.

Comment: I think you have to *at the very least*, make sure that $h(f)$ is defined (or something like that; it's been years since I've thought of real analysis).

Comment: If $h$ is continuous then this is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any sequence $x_n \to x$ and define $f_n(x)=x_n$. Then $h \circ f_n \to h \circ f$ if and only if $h$ is continuous at $x$. Hence the continuity of $h$ is a necessary condition. Can you decide whether it is also sufficient?